# Potential Bug(s) with SuperLU configuration on Windows

Tags: sparse-matrix, msys, sundials

I am trying to run the SuperLU_MT example programs in SUNDIALS (IDA).

I have successfully built SuperLU_MT libraries on Windows from source. I am using the pthread implementation -- successfully built the corresponding IDA modules/libraries as well.

*Note that I'm using MSYS2 MINGW64*

I successfully compiled and linked `test_sunlinsol_superlumt.c`. The executable, however, is throwing runtime error: **"COLAMD failed at line 58 in file get_perm_c.c"**
[COLAMD ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuaVO.png)

The same error is thrown when running the provided superlu example codes (heat2d_sps, roberts_sps, etc).

My setup on Linux is identical apart from the vendor [BLAS](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-openblas64?repo=mingw64) library. However, the programs run as expected on Linux...

*There are NUMEROUS places where I might have made configuration errors. It is not possible for me to retrace the full process here, but I'm happy to provide more specific details when prompted*

Repository link (if helpful): https://github.com/AdiMatam/IDA-Temp

*I am trying to run the `test_linsol_superlumt` program in the root directory, using the `temp.sh` 'build' script.*

Comment: MSYS2 has a prebuilt `mingw-w64-x86_64-superlu` package, it's the same library you use, right? What if you use this instead of building from source?

Comment: Problem is that package ONLY supports "superlu" -- for sequential machines. However, I'm specifically building "superlu_**mt**" -- which is for shared memory parallel machines. It doesn't look like MSYS2 has a package for that...

Comment: The main confusion for me is: what 'module' would be responsible for COLAMD failure. 

1) Vendor BLAS implementation?
2) SuperLU_MT library build?
3) Highly doubtful this is relevant but.... Using pthread instead of openmp (or other alternatives)?